# Parallelizing a for loop which downloads information from Oracle in R

Tags: sql, r, oracle, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have a function which can be read like

```
`For every period{

 run an specific query in the Oracle server
 and download the data

}`
```

My question is regarding how can I easily create different instances running a step of the for loop because most of the time is consumed sending the query individually but if I run several queries at the same time they do not get slower.

My goal is to, given that I can use 40 threads at a time, run N different R sessions where each session runs a step of the loop (and a query itself) to speed up the work

Comment: I might be wrong but I think you can only parallelize up to the number of cores. 40 does sound like a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own parallel for loop:

```
library(future)
plan(multiprocess, workers = N)

res <- listenv::listenv()
for (period in periods) {
  res[[period]] %<-% {
    query_and_download(period)
  }
}
res <- as.list(res)
```

or use a parallel lapply call:

```
library(future.apply)
plan(multiprocess, workers = N)
res <- future_lapply(periods, FUN = function(period) {
  query_and_download(period)
})
```